# Is there any event that fires when WPF animation ends?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, doubleanimation

Is there any event that fires when WPF Animation ends?

```cs
void HideDefaultScreenImageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideDefaultScreenImageTimer.Stop();

    var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.45)));
    DefaultScreenImage.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);
    // I need some event when an animation ENDS and within that event I want to remove 
    // Image (DefaultScreenImage) from Canvas.
    MainCanvas.Children.Remove(DefaultScreenImage);
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Yes there is.

[The Completed Event (MSDN)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed).

---

So your code becomes:

```cs
void HideDefaultScreenImageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HideDefaultScreenImageTimer.Stop();

    var doubleAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.45)));
    doubleAnimation.Completed += (sender, eArgs) => MainCanvas.Children.Remove(DefaultScreenImage);

    DefaultScreenImage.BeginAnimation(UIElement.OpacityProperty, doubleAnimation);
}
```